# Dar click a un elemento span que esta dentro de un iframe con vba

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

La pagina muestra un texto que dice MANTENIMIENTOS; al dar click con el mouse habilita unas cajas de texto, el problema es que no existe un id o un name para poder acceder al elemento por id o name.

según yo con mi código de visual trato de encontrar la palabra mantenimientos para poder darle click, no puedo acceder a ese elemento.

por lo que veo, el bucle se detiene cuando encuentra el iframe y por lo tanto no encuentra los elementos que están dentro del iframe.

anexo un poco del código de la pagina.

```
<frame name= "hexdesktop" src="ke00.jsp" frameborder="1">
<html>
<head></head>
body>
<iframe src="ke010.jsp" frameborder="1">
<html>
</html>
<body>
<div class = "dhtmlxlayoutobject">
<table>
tbody>
<tr>
<td class = "standartTreeRow" parentobject = "[object-object]" 
style="Cursor:hand">
<span class = "standartTreeRow">MANTENIMIENTOS </span>
</td>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
</frame>
```

Mi codigo de visual es

```
Private Sub Extraccion()
Public IE As Object
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim frame As HTMLFrameElement
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")    
Set HTMLdoc = IE.document
Set frame = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("HEXDESKTOP")(0)
Set HTMLdoc = frame.contentDocument      
For Each er In HTMLdoc.all
If er.innerText = "MANTENIMIENTOS" Then
er.Click
End If
Next er
```

Comment: queres simular el click? y es necesario?? o podes hacer directamente la llamada que hace el click?

Comment: Si yo coloco el cursor del mouse encima de la palabra MANTENIMIENTOS y doy click, se habilitan unas cajas de texto en las cuales puedo hacer consultas, entonces lo que necesito por medio de visual es acceder al elemento, ya sea al tag span o al tag td, o por  por medio de innertext, encontrar "MANTENIMIENTOS" y así simular el click para habilitar las cajas de texto. @gbianchi